# Java serialization String == and equals

Tags: java

I write an object to a file and then I read it.

Then I make "if" to compare object's arguments. For example "genreDescription" is "Action".

```
 if (genreDescription == "Action" ) {
  System.out.println("Some text");
        }
```

Before import == and equals produce expected and the same result.
After import equals work but == doesn't. 
I tried removing blank spaces. I also manually updated object's "genreDescription" to "Action" right before if.
It affects only String, because if "gendreDescription" is int like 6 then it's normal. Why?

Comment: I red these topics but they don't explain why it affects only Strings and not ints. Can you say that?

Comment: Strings are objects ints not.

Comment: JAVA Strings are mapping in heap memory , so compareing strings is comparing their address